# Use AOT for build, JIT for serve

Tags: angular-cli

Currently, I use AOT compilation in my whole Angular project.
However, I'd like to use JIT for any config within the `serve` [architect](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#default-architect-builders-and-targets). How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "fooProject": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "buildOptimizer": true
          },
          "configurations": {},
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fooProject:build",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "vendorChunk": false
          },
          "configurations": {},
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In which case I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'.
```

Apparently the AOT-related options (such as `buildOptimizer`) are not removed before the compilation is started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `buildOptimizer` and `aot` options in your serve object. This is because you use the `browserTarget:fooProject:build`. This will get the settings defined in the `fooProject.build` object, and -merge- these with the serve options. So the options object is not overwritten, but merged together.

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "fooProject:build",
    "optimization": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "aot": false
   },
   "configurations": {},
}
```